# How can I get Python's slice operator in Kotlin

Tags: python, kotlin

Python has a slice operator and I want it in Kotlin.

I want the following code in Kotlin

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
println(
        list[5]
)
println(
        list[2, 5].joinToString()
)
println(
        list[2, 10, 2].joinToString()
)
val mutableList = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
mutableList[2, 10, 2] = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(
        mutableList.joinToString()
)
```

to output the following:

```
6
3, 4, 5
3, 5, 7, 9
1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 10
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: What's wrong with `list.slice(2..4).joinToString(",")`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.  Just doesn't solve the problem.  For one thing, I want to be able to mutate the list as shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished using extension functions and operator overloading.  The following code will solve the problem you provide.  With some adjustment, it would handle all the other options that Python provides as well.

```
operator fun <T : Any> Iterable<T>.get(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int = 1): Iterable<T> {
    check(start < end)
    check(step > 0)
    val iterator = iterator()
    var s = 0
    return generateSequence {
        while (s < start && iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next()
            s++
        }
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (s < end) {
                val value = iterator.next()
                repeat(step - 1) { s++; if (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next() }
                s++
                value
            } else {
                null
            }
        } else {
            null
        }
    }.asIterable<T>()
}

operator fun <T : Any> MutableList<T>.set(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int = 1, newElts: Iterable<T>) {
    check(start < end)
    check(step > 0)
    val iterator = iterator()
    val newIterator = newElts.iterator()
    var s = 0
    while (s < start && iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next()
        s++
    }
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (s < end) {
            if (newIterator.hasNext()) {
                this[s] = newIterator.next()
                iterator.next()
                repeat(step - 1) {
                    s++;
                    if (iterator.hasNext())
                        iterator.next()
                    else
                        return
                }
                s++
            } else
                return
        }
    }
}
```

[gladed](https://www.reddit.com/user/gladed) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/6wtuoe/pythons_slice_operator_in_kotlin/dmawuug/) came up with another solution that doesn't use Python's syntax but I quite like.

```
operator fun <T: Any> Iterable<T>.get(range: IntProgression) = asSequence().run {
    range.mapNotNull { index -> elementAtOrNull(index) }
}

operator fun <T: Any> MutableList<T>.set(range: ClosedRange<Int>, from: Iterable<T>) {
    for (i in range.start..minOf(range.endInclusive, size - 1)) removeAt(range.start)
    addAll(range.start, from.toList())
}

@Test
fun slice() {
    val list = mutableListOf(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    assertEquals(listOf(7, 8, 9), list[2..4])
    assertEquals(listOf(10, 8), list[5 downTo 2 step 2])

    list[2..4] = listOf(77)
    assertEquals(listOf(5, 6, 77, 10), list)

    list[0..10] = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    assertEquals(listOf(1, 2, 3), list)
}
```

Comment: You're answering your own question?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 It is fine to answer your own question, see: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Absolutely it is! But the answer came in just a few seconds after the question, like it was prepared or something.

Comment: It was prepared.  Part of the community process.  Sharing solutions.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question.

Comment: It's just a little weird that you address yourself in second person, such as "The following code will solve the problem you provide."

Comment: I think it's better this way. The answer follows how most answers are worded so gives a sense of familiarity to the reader, instead of "I solved it like by doing blah blah..."